# What's the best way to parse a definition list using XPath?

Tags: python, xslt, xpath

I'm using Python + xPath to parse some HTML but I'm having trouble parsing an definition list. An example  would be as follows:

`<dl>

    <dt>Section One</dt>

    <dd>Child one</dd>

    <dd>Child one.2</dd>

    <dt>Section Two</dt>

    <dd>Child two</dd>

</dl>`

I want to transform this into an output like:
`{'Section One' : ['Child one','Child one.2'], 'Section Two' : ['Child two']}`

I having difficulty though because the way the  is structured, there's not that same hierarchy you find in the output.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use XPath? You could just iterate over the document and get the desired result.

Comment: What you need is a transformation, XSLT with output method `text` would suffice. Or some Python mechanisms.

Comment: XPath 1.0 data type are node set (unordered and uniques), number (double), string and boolean. No one of these is a structured data type like you want to. You need to iterate over `dt` elements and then sibling `dd` elements, whether you select the elements with XPath or any other DOM API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A single-expression XPath 1.0 solution, if possible at all, would be difficult to write and understand**.

**Here is a simple XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="dd"
      use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::dt[1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="dl">
  { <xsl:apply-templates select="dt"/> }
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="dt">
  <xsl:text/>'<xsl:value-of select="."/>' : [ <xsl:text/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
   <xsl:text> ]</xsl:text>
   <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">, </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="dd">
  <xsl:text/>'<xsl:value-of select="."/>'<xsl:text/>
   <xsl:if test="not(position()=last())">, </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<dl>
    <dt>Section One</dt>
    <dd>Child one</dd>
    <dd>Child one.2</dd>
    <dt>Section Two</dt>
    <dd>Child two</dd>
</dl>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
  { 'Section One' : [ 'Child one', 'Child one.2' ], 'Section Two' : [ 'Child two' ] }
```

**Explanation**: An `xsl:key` is defined and used to capture the 1 --> many relationship between a `dt` and the immediately following siblings `dt` elements.

Comment: Nice, but I understood the "output" of the original question to be a python dictionary, rather than the exact literal "output".

Comment: @Steven: You may be right. The OP said "I want to transform this into an output like ..." and this is exactly what I am giving him. In case something else is wanted, he still can use the ideas from my solution, or make his question more specific then I could provide him again with the wanted answer. He can even use this solution to generate Python source code.

Answer (score 3):

A solution without xpath, using lxml (which you are probably already using if you are using xpath?):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from lxml import etree

dl = etree.fromstring('''<dl>
<dt>Section One</dt>
<dd>Child one</dd>
<dd>Child one.2</dd>
<dt>Section Two</dt>
<dd>Child two</dd>
</dl>''')

result = defaultdict(list)
for dt in dl.findall('dt'):
    for child in dt.itersiblings(): # iterate over following siblings
        if child.tag != 'dd':
            break # stop at the first element that is not a dd
        result[dt.text].append(child.text)

print dict(result)
```

(any xpath solution I can come up with is worse than this, it seems)

Comment: +1 - Much prefer this elegant solution to the XSLT proposed alternative. Thanks Steven, I've put it to good use.